# How to count from three tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I have 3 tables `post`, `post_like` and `post_comment`.

I'd like to count `likes` and `comments` of posts by a user:

post:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(30)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| description | text         | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| link        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | ''                |                |

+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

post_like:

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_id | int(30)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| user_id | int(30)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| time    | varchar(50) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

post_comment:

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(30)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_id | int(20)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| user_id | int(20)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| text    | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| time    | varchar(100) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here is the query that I've came up with:

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    COUNT(l.post_id) "likes", 
    COUNT(c.post_id) "comments"
FROM 
    post p
    INNER JOIN post_like l ON p.id = l.post_id 
    INNER JOIN post_comment c ON c.post_id = l.post_id
WHERE 
    p.user_id=55 
GROUP BY 
    l.post_id
ORDER BY
    p.created_at DESC
```

The problem is that the query returns only one row, while there are several posts.

I have tried different tricks and looked at similar questions but could not find the solution.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick-and-dirty way to do what you want is to use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT p.id, p.user_id, p.description, p.link,
       COUNT(DISTINCT l.id) as num_likes, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) as num_comments
FROM post p LEFT JOIN
     post_like l
     ON p.id = l.post_id LEFT JOIN
     post_comment c
     ON p.id = c.post_id
WHERE p.user_id=55 
GROUP BY p.id, p.user_id, p.description, p.link
ORDER BY p.created_at DESC;
```

The more advanced way is to aggregate before you `join`, but this method will probably work for your data.

Comment: Well this returns only one row, while there are several posts by user `55`. Also it should use `p.id ` instead of  `p.post_id` .

Comment: @Milkyway . . . This returns the same number of rows as your query.  The only differences are that comments and likes are included for all posts, and the counts should be correct.

Comment: Works great. Thanks!